# repeat function based on switch inside function

Tags: c++

I'm not able to figure out why this results in a unbreakable loop. the function should set repeat to false, but it does not carry outside of the function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void DayCheck(char day);

int main()
{
    char day1;
    bool repeat;
    do 
    {
        cout << "\nEnter day: ";
        cin >> day1;
        DayCheck(day1);
    } while (repeat = false);
    cout << day1;
    return 0;
}

void DayCheck(char day1)
{
    bool repeat;
    // Check whether the user entered meaningful input
    switch (day1)
    {
        case 'M': break;
        case 'T': break;
        case 'W': break;
        case 'F': break;
        case 'S': break;
        default:
            cout << "\nThat was an invalid input.";
            repeat = false;
        break;
    }
    return;
}
```

This is an error checking function for a larger project. the program takes a day code input as MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU.

Comment: Properly indenting the code will help follow the flow of the code.  Every line in your post is flushed to the left margin, making the code harder to follow.

Comment: You have two different `repeat` variables.  Just because they have the same name doesn't mean they are the same variable.

Comment: so how do i use the repeat variable from the global definition inside of the called function?

Answer (score 1):

> while (repeat = false);

The use of the assignment operator here is wrong, since this will not compare any values, just equates the two. You need to replace it with

> while (repeat == false);

Also in the DayChecker function, you declare a checker yet return a void and only set a local variable to 0. What I'd recommend is:

```
bool DayCheck(char day1) {
    bool repeat;

    // Check whether the user entered meaningful input
    switch (day1)
    {
        case 'M': return true; break;
        case 'T': return true; break;
        case 'W': return true; break;
        case 'F': return true; break;
        case 'S': return true; break;
    default:
        cout << "\nThat was an invalid input.\n";
        return false;
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then just replace line 12 (10 if you do not count the empty lines, 9 if you start from 0):

> repeat = DayCheck(day1);

so that you can confirm it's a valid date and stop being in an infinite loop.

#### TL;DR:

== != =

`while (repeat = false);` is not right, make it `while (repeat == false);`